# Reindex status stuck on "Reindex Required"

Tags: magento-1.9, reindex

[image: Magento Reindex Stuck on "Reindex Required"]

As you can see above, when I reindex I am shown a message stating that the reindex was successful. However the status of the index does not change from "**Reindex Required**".

Efforts:

- `Removed files within ./var/locks/`
- `Truncated index tables`
- Tried shell command. Despite success messages I still see "Reindex Required"

  ```
  $ php ./shell/indexer.php --reindexall
  Product Attributes index was rebuilt successfully in 00:00:02
  Product Prices index was rebuilt successfully in 00:00:01  
  Catalog Search Index index was rebuilt successfully in 00:00:05
  Stock Status index was rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
  Tag Aggregation Data index was rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
  Catalog URL Rewrites index was rebuilt successfully in 00:00:41
  Product Flat Data index was rebuilt successfully in 00:00:03
  Category Flat Data index was rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
  Category Products index was rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
  ```

Comment: Please try to index from command line

Comment: @AmitBera - I apologize, I should have mentioned that I have given that a shot prior to creating this message. Please see my updated post for details.

Comment: Do the lock files get recreated but then not removed?  Perhaps you should check the folder permissions for var/locks so that they can be removed - perhaps chmod to 777 for starters, see if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Humbled, I submit my resolution to this problem.

Magento was reading from a different database than it was updating. In `.app/etc/local.xml` I had implemented `<core_read>`,`<core_write>`, and  in a previous dev environment and no longer needed to reference two databases.

I removed the  sections to resolve this.

Comment: Oops? lol. It was too weird after reindexing from cli.

Comment: Exactly. And when saving other admin configurations, the saves being reported as successful, and not seeing the updates C=